# Selenium options don't work with headless mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 with Selenium 4.1. When I run my code regularly, it works fine, but when I set it to headless, I don't think any of the options work including the Guest, inPrivate, or incognito mode because I keep getting 2FA prompts as if it is logging in with my cached credentials.

Here are my options with EdgeDriver:

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArgument("-guest");
options.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("headless");

using (var driver = new EdgeDriver(DRIVERS_PATH, options))
{
   driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
   driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

   var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));

   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(recordUrl);
   // get a 2FA prompt here 
}
```

Or when using ChromeOptions

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--headless");
            options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.AddArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
            options.AddArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
            options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.AddArguments("--no-first-run");
            options.AddArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
            options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.AddArguments("--test-type");
            options.AddArguments("--user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36\"");
            //options.AddArguments("--guest");
            options.AddArguments("--incognito");
```

Once again, if I remove the headless option, then it works fine, but with headless, I don't think any of the options are taking. When I take a screenshot of the page:

```
var screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile($"{filePath}.jpg", ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It shows the message saying it sent me a 2FA notice which I then receive on my phone. Why would it be doing this if I was in incognito mode?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with headless chrome and geo settings.

I found that in headless, auto accepting geo location is not supported (headless will have some things removed)

Headless is a stripped down version of Chrome

See reference: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11542#issuecomment-1380947933